# c++ creating string using char array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

currently learning strings, i have the following cases :

```
string s;
s[0]='a'; s[1]='b';
cout<<s;

string s; s.clear();
s+='a'; s+='b';
cout<<s;
```

I get empty string as output from 1st example, and the 2nd works fine.
I get that the 1st is undef behavior and that we 'push' an element the second time instead of assigning a value.
Any more clarification will be appreciated.

Comment: What clarification are you looking for?  You identified that the first example is undefined behavior, so are you trying to figure out why?

Comment: in both cases the string has size 0 but we are only allowed to increase that size by adding not assigning. Is there anything more I should know about this?

Comment: You can only use `[]` to assign to a string position that already exists, using `[]` doesn't grow the string. You could do this `string s; s.resize(2); s[0]='a'; s[1]='b'; cout<<s;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator `[]` returns a reference to the character at position `pos` in the string, it does reading value rather than insert and resize `std::string`.

You cannot insert to **null** assigned value, thats why you get `undefined behaviour`. First resize the string and then try to insert using `[]` the operator.